# Nx build fails on AWS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

`nx build` succeeds locally but fails on Amplify with this error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

This happens even though I don't use `useRef` anywhere in my code.

I've tried adding an `error.tsx` file since the errors say they're coming from prerendering the /404 and /500 pages, but that didn't work.

I'm using Next.js 13.4.19 with the apps directory.

Here is my Amplify CDK code:

```
    const amplifyApp = new amplify.App(this, 'cupid-react-app', {
      sourceCodeProvider: new amplify.GitHubSourceCodeProvider({
        owner: 'cupid-dev',
        repository: 'cupid',
        oauthToken: SecretValue.secretsManager('test/github-pat'),
      }),
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObjectToYaml({
        version: 1,
        frontend: {
          phases: {
            preBuild: {
              commands: [
                // Install the correct Node version, defined in .nvmrc
                'nvm install',
                'nvm use',
                // Install pnpm
                'corepack enable',
                'corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate',
                // Avoid memory issues with node
                'export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192',
                // Ensure node_modules are correctly included in the build artifacts
                'pnpm install',
              ],
            },
            build: {
              commands: [
                'pnpm exec nx report',
                'pnpm exec nx run frontend:build --no-cloud',
              ],
            },
          },
          artifacts: {
            baseDirectory: 'apps/frontend/.next',
            files: ['**/*'],
          },
          cache: {
            paths: ['node_modules/**/*'],
          },
        },
      }),
    });
```

Here is the full logging from the frontend build on Amplify:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: nvm install
2023-09-09T06:27:19.055Z [INFO]: Found '/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/.nvmrc' with version <16>
2023-09-09T06:27:19.518Z [INFO]: Downloading and installing node v16.20.2...
2023-09-09T06:27:19.663Z [WARNING]: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.20.2/node-v16.20.2-linux-x64.tar.gz...
2023-09-09T06:27:19.780Z [WARNING]: #########################################
2023-09-09T06:27:19.781Z [WARNING]: ############################### 100.0%
2023-09-09T06:27:19.796Z [WARNING]: Computing checksum with sha256sum
2023-09-09T06:27:19.882Z [WARNING]: Checksums matched!
2023-09-09T06:27:21.097Z [INFO]: Now using node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
2023-09-09T06:27:21.128Z [INFO]: Installing default global packages from /root/.nvm/default-packages...
2023-09-09T06:27:21.128Z [INFO]: npm install -g --quiet yarn@1.22.0
2023-09-09T06:27:22.665Z [INFO]: added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s
2023-09-09T06:27:22.668Z [INFO]: found 0 vulnerabilities
2023-09-09T06:27:22.673Z [INFO]: # Executing command: nvm use
2023-09-09T06:27:22.681Z [INFO]: Found '/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/.nvmrc' with version <16>
2023-09-09T06:27:23.354Z [INFO]: Now using node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
2023-09-09T06:27:23.355Z [INFO]: # Executing command: corepack enable
2023-09-09T06:27:23.443Z [INFO]: # Executing command: corepack prepare pnpm@latest --activate
2023-09-09T06:27:23.779Z [INFO]: Preparing pnpm@latest for immediate activation...
2023-09-09T06:27:24.233Z [INFO]: # Executing command: export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
2023-09-09T06:27:24.234Z [INFO]: # Executing command: pnpm install
2023-09-09T06:27:25.114Z [INFO]: Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
2023-09-09T06:27:25.546Z [INFO]: Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
2023-09-09T06:27:25.760Z [INFO]: Packages: +7 -7
                                 +++++++-------
2023-09-09T06:27:26.548Z [INFO]: Progress: resolved 7, reused 0, downloaded 4, added 4
2023-09-09T06:27:27.547Z [INFO]: Progress: resolved 7, reused 0, downloaded 7, added 6
2023-09-09T06:27:27.591Z [INFO]: Progress: resolved 7, reused 0, downloaded 7, added 7, done
2023-09-09T06:27:31.430Z [INFO]: dependencies:
                                 + @auth0/auth0-react 2.2.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb 3.391.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/client-mturk 3.391.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/client-s3 3.391.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager 3.408.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb 3.391.0
                                 + @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner 3.391.0
                                 + @chakra-ui/icons 2.1.0
                                 + @chakra-ui/react 2.8.0
                                 + @dnd-kit/core 6.0.8
                                 + @dnd-kit/sortable 7.0.2
                                 + @dnd-kit/utilities 3.2.1
                                 + @emotion/react 11.11.1
                                 + @emotion/styled 11.11.0
                                 + @swc/helpers 0.5.1
                                 + @types/auth0 3.3.4
                                 + auth0 3.7.0
                                 + aws-lambda 1.0.7
                                 + aws-sdk 2.1440.0
                                 + browser-image-compression 2.0.2
                                 + constructs 10.2.50
                                 + dotenv 16.3.1
                                 + framer-motion 10.15.1
                                 + jsonwebtoken 9.0.0
                                 + jwks-rsa 3.0.1
                                 - next 13.4.13
                                 + react 18.2.0
                                 + react-dom 18.2.0
                                 + react-icons 4.10.1
                                 + react-image-crop 10.1.5
                                 + stripe 12.9.0
                                 + superagent-proxy 3.0.0
                                 + tslib 2.6.1
                                 + uuid 9.0.0
                                 + xml-js 1.6.11
                                 + zod 3.22.1
                                 + zod-validation-error 1.3.1
                                 devDependencies:
                                 + @aws-cdk/aws-amplify-alpha 2.90.0-alpha.0
                                 + @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers-alpha 2.90.0-alpha.0
                                 + @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations-alpha 2.90.0-alpha.0
                                 + @babel/preset-react 7.22.5
                                 + @nx/cypress 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/eslint-plugin 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/jest 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/js 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/linter 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/react 16.6.0
                                 + @nx/workspace 16.6.0
                                 + @swc/cli 0.1.62
                                 + @swc/core 1.3.51
                                 + @testing-library/react 14.0.0
                                 + @types/aws-lambda 8.10.119
                                 + @types/jest 29.5.3
                                 + @types/jsonwebtoken 9.0.2
                                 + @types/node 18.14.2
                                 + @types/react 18.2.14
                                 + @types/react-dom 18.2.6
                                 + @types/uuid 9.0.2
                                 + @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin 5.62.0
                                 + @typescript-eslint/parser 5.62.0
                                 + aws-cdk-lib 2.90.0
                                 + babel-jest 29.6.2
                                 + cypress 12.17.3
                                 + eslint 8.15.0
                                 + eslint-config-next 13.4.1
                                 + eslint-config-prettier 8.1.0
                                 + eslint-plugin-cypress 2.13.4
                                 + eslint-plugin-import 2.27.5
                                 + eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y 6.7.1
                                 + eslint-plugin-react 7.32.2
                                 + eslint-plugin-react-hooks 4.6.0
                                 + jest 29.6.2
                                 + jest-environment-jsdom 29.6.2
                                 + next 13.4.19
                                 + nx 16.6.0
                                 + nx-cloud 16.4.0
                                 + prettier 2.8.8
                                 + ts-jest 29.1.1
                                 + ts-node 10.9.1
                                 + typescript 5.1.6
2023-09-09T06:27:31.680Z [INFO]: Done in 7.3s
2023-09-09T06:27:31.724Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-09-09T06:27:31.724Z [INFO]: # Executing command: pnpm exec nx report
2023-09-09T06:27:35.594Z [INFO]: 
2023-09-09T06:27:35.596Z [INFO]: >  NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template
                                 Node   : 16.20.2
                                 OS     : linux-x64
                                 pnpm   : 8.7.4
                                 
                                 nx                 : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/js             : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/jest           : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/linter         : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/workspace      : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/cypress        : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/devkit         : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/eslint-plugin  : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/next           : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/react          : 16.6.0
                                 @nrwl/tao          : 16.6.0
                                 @nx/web            : 16.6.0
                                 nx-cloud           : 16.4.0
                                 typescript         : 5.1.6
2023-09-09T06:27:35.611Z [INFO]: # Executing command: pnpm exec nx run frontend:build --no-cloud
2023-09-09T06:27:36.575Z [INFO]: 
2023-09-09T06:27:36.575Z [INFO]: >  NX   Nx Cloud Will Not Be Used
2023-09-09T06:27:36.575Z [INFO]: Nx will continue running, but nothing will be written or read from the remote cache.
                                 Run details will also not be available in the Nx Cloud UI.
                                 
                                 If this wasn't intentional, check for the NX_NO_CLOUD environment variable, the --no-cloud flag
2023-09-09T06:27:36.581Z [INFO]: 
2023-09-09T06:27:36.581Z [INFO]: > nx run frontend:build:production
2023-09-09T06:27:39.208Z [INFO]: - [33mwarn[39m No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
2023-09-09T06:27:39.213Z [INFO]: [35m[1mAttention[22m[39m: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2023-09-09T06:27:39.214Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
2023-09-09T06:27:39.214Z [INFO]: [36mhttps://nextjs.org/telemetry[39m
2023-09-09T06:27:39.293Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Creating an optimized production build...
2023-09-09T06:28:07.132Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Compiled successfully
2023-09-09T06:28:07.134Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Skipping linting
                                 - [36minfo[39m Checking validity of types...
2023-09-09T06:28:16.192Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Collecting page data...
2023-09-09T06:28:28.574Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Generating static pages (0/5)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.636Z [WARNING]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
2023-09-09T06:28:28.636Z [WARNING]: at exports.useRef (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
                                    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.10_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:85:35)
                                    at Wc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.637Z [WARNING]: at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.637Z [WARNING]: Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
2023-09-09T06:28:28.638Z [WARNING]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
                                    at exports.useRef (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
                                    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.10_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:85:35)
                                    at Wc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.639Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Generating static pages (1/5)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.639Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Generating static pages (2/5)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.857Z [WARNING]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
                                    at exports.useRef (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
                                    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.10_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:85:35)
                                    at Wc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.858Z [WARNING]: Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
                                    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
                                    at exports.useRef (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:337)
                                    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_@babel+core@7.22.10_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:85:35)
                                    at Wc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
                                    at Z (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
                                    at Zc (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.859Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Generating static pages (3/5)
2023-09-09T06:28:28.933Z [INFO]: external isAuthenticated: false
2023-09-09T06:28:28.936Z [INFO]: external isAuthenticated: false
2023-09-09T06:28:29.004Z [INFO]: home page isAuthenticated: false
2023-09-09T06:28:29.043Z [INFO]: - [36minfo[39m Generating static pages (5/5)
2023-09-09T06:28:29.044Z [WARNING]: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
                                    /_error: /404
                                    /_error: /500
2023-09-09T06:28:29.089Z [WARNING]: [1m[31mError occurred while trying to run the npx next build [39m[22m
2023-09-09T06:28:29.090Z [WARNING]: [1m[31mError: Command failed: npx next build [39m[22m
2023-09-09T06:28:29.090Z [WARNING]: [1m[31m    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:861:11)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at execSync (node:child_process:932:15)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at /codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/@nx+next@16.6.0_@babel+core@7.22.10_@swc+core@1.3.51_@types+node@18.14.2_eslint@8.15.0_next@1_3zyt67gsgqavcro3u3avhmtkki/node_modules/@nx/next/src/executors/build/build.impl.js:49:42[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at /codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.1/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:169:75[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at new Promise (<anonymous>)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at Object.__awaiter (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/tslib@2.6.1/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:165:16)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at buildExecutor (/codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/@nx+next@16.6.0_@babel+core@7.22.10_@swc+core@1.3.51_@types+node@18.14.2_eslint@8.15.0_next@1_3zyt67gsgqavcro3u3avhmtkki/node_modules/@nx/next/src/executors/build/build.impl.js:20:20)[39m[22m
                                    [1m[31m    at /codebuild/output/src2171615067/src/cupid/node_modules/.pnpm/nx@16.6.0_@swc+core@1.3.51/node_modules/nx/src/command-line/run/run.js:102:23[39m[22m
2023-09-09T06:28:29.099Z [INFO]: 
2023-09-09T06:28:29.099Z [INFO]: 
                                 >  NX   Running target build for project frontend failed
                                 Failed tasks:
                                 
                                 - frontend:build:production
                                 
                                 Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
2023-09-09T06:28:29.112Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-09-09T06:28:29.113Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-09-09T06:28:29.113Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-09-09T06:28:29.113Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-09-09T06:28:29.224Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-09-09T06:28:29.224Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Here is the logging from a local build:

```
 pnpm exec nx run frontend:build:production --no-cloud

> nx run frontend:build:production

- info Creating an optimized production build...
- info Compiled successfully
- info Skipping linting
- info Checking validity of types...
- info Collecting page data...
- info Generating static pages (0/5)
- info Generating static pages (1/5)
- info Generating static pages (2/5)
- info Generating static pages (3/5)
external isAuthenticated: false
external isAuthenticated: false
home page isAuthenticated: false
- info Generating static pages (5/5)
- info Finalizing page optimization...
Route (app)                                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                                      3.81 kB         265 kB
├ ○ /api/hello                                             0 B                0 B
├ ○ /myroute                                               494 B           262 kB
└ λ /myOtherRoute                                          1.33 kB         263 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                              261 kB
  ├ chunks/263-8bc21cf60bb2ece8.js                         10.4 kB
  ├ chunks/274aaff5-7e0e8a490177c4de.js                    400 B
  ├ chunks/284-9e0f8e78adc07c00.js                         26.1 kB
  ├ chunks/2f5b3802-f87feb4f4269018d.js                    982 B
  ├ chunks/36d85533-a97fdb941b3ad061.js                    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/657-a70e1fa7bf317daa.js                         170 kB
  ├ chunks/a133451a-d1625a266cd23fa9.js                    327 B
  ├ chunks/df73fcc7-00b254edc0e7cd41.js                    532 B
  ├ chunks/main-app-3f7701bf0827a090.js                    218 B
  └ chunks/webpack-e3cf27a050779d77.js                     1.84 kB
Route (pages)                                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                                   182 B          76.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                              76.5 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-eb124dc7acb3bb04.js                   45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-d2ae93d2867e3148.js                        29.4 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-a6c6c24e6ddb3541.js                  195 B
  └ chunks/webpack-e3cf27a050779d77.js                     1.84 kB
λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

 ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Successfully ran target build for project frontend (29s)
```

Here is the output of `nx report`:

```
   Locally:
   Node   : 18.12.1
   OS     : darwin-x64
   pnpm   : 8.6.12

   nx                 : 16.6.0
   @nx/js             : 16.6.0
   @nx/jest           : 16.6.0
   @nx/linter         : 16.6.0
   @nx/workspace      : 16.6.0
   @nx/cypress        : 16.6.0
   @nx/devkit         : 16.6.0
   @nx/eslint-plugin  : 16.6.0
   @nx/next           : 16.6.0
   @nx/react          : 16.6.0
   @nrwl/tao          : 16.6.0
   @nx/web            : 16.6.0
   nx-cloud           : 16.4.0
   @nrwl/nx-cloud     : 16.2.0
   typescript         : 5.1.6

On Amplify:
   Node   : 16.19.0
   OS     : linux-x64
   pnpm   : 8.7.4
                                 
   nx                 : 16.6.0
   @nx/js             : 16.6.0
   @nx/jest           : 16.6.0
   @nx/linter         : 16.6.0
   @nx/workspace      : 16.6.0
   @nx/cypress        : 16.6.0
   @nx/devkit         : 16.6.0
   @nx/eslint-plugin  : 16.6.0
   @nx/next           : 16.6.0
   @nx/react          : 16.6.0
   @nrwl/tao          : 16.6.0
   @nx/web            : 16.6.0
   nx-cloud           : 16.4.0
   typescript         : 5.1.6
```